# javascript regular expression validate mm/dd

Tags: javascript, regex

```
s="12/15"
r=/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2])){1}\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])){1}/g
s.match(r)

> ["12/1"]
```

I was trying to validate date format mm/dd
but the matched string missed the last digit.

Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Cheng

Comment: @mu is too short, `06/31` we can exclude. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this regex: `^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$`

If you want matches in string, use word boundaries, e.g.:

```
\b(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b
```

---

```
(?x)
^
(
    0?[1-9]   # 1-9 or 01-09
    |
    1[0-2]    # 10 11 12
)
/
(
    0?[1-9]   # 1-9 or 01-09
    |
    [12][0-9] # 10-29
    |
    3[01]     # 30 31
)
$
```

---

Large regex:

```
(?x)
\b(?:
(?<month>
    0?[13578]
    |
    1[02]
)
/
(?<day>
    0?[1-9]
    |
    [12][0-9]
    |
    3[01]
)
|
(?<month>
    0?[469]
    |
    11
)
/
(?<day>
    0?[1-9]
    |
    [12][0-9]
    |
    30
)
|
(?<month>
    0?2
)
/
(?<day>
    0?[1-9]
    |
    [12][0-9]
)
)
\b
```

Comment: @cheng, Forgot beginning and end of string, i.e. `^` and `$`.

Comment: hold on, it wonldn't work in the following string
r = /^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/g
ss = "2/10 asdfasdfadsf 2/15 dfsgsdfgdf 2/17 dfghdfghdfgh"
ss.match(r)
>null

Comment: it works with "12/15" but not  "2/10 asdfasdfadsf 2/15 dfsgsdfgdf 2/17 dfghdfghdfgh"
also, the order doesn't matter, as long as I have the $

Comment: @cheng, Use second regex (`\b(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\b`). In string `2/10 asdfasdfadsf 2/15 dfsgsdfgdf 2/17 dfghdfghdfgh` it will match: `2/10`, `2/15` and `2/17`, I tested.

Comment: it works. thank you very much! But do you know why the old one(with ^$) doesn't work?

Comment: @cheng, That is because `^` means beginning of line or string, `$` means end of line or string. If your input is `2/10` or `2/15` it should match. If you input is `a 2/10` it won't.

Answer (score 1):

At first I removed some of your brackets.

One possibility to fix your problem is to use anchors

```
 ^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]){1}\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]){1}$
```

This would be the solution if your string is only the date. Those anchors `^` and `$` ensure that the expression is matched from the start to the end.

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ua0f)

The second possibility is to change the order in your last part.

```
(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]){1}\/(1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1]|0?[1-9]){1}
```

Because the first part `0?[1-9]` matched your `15` your expression succeeded and that was it. If we put this to the end then at first it tries to match the numbers consisting of two digits, then it matches the `15`